# Pandas merge two dataframes summing values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes with partly repeated entries:

```
source1=pandas.DataFrame({'key':['a','b'],'value':[1,2]})
#  key  value
#0   a      1
#1   b      2
source2=pandas.DataFrame({'key':['b','c'],'value':[3,0]})
#  key  value
#0   b      3
#1   c      0
```

What do I need to do with `source1` and `source2` in order to get resulting frame with following entries:

```
#  key  value
#0   a      1
#1   b      5
#2   c      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With grouping:

```
>>> pd.concat([source1, source2]).groupby('key', as_index=False).sum()
  key  value
0   a      1
1   b      5
2   c      0
```

Comment: Another good option.

Comment: I've switched the answer to this, because I've been able to reuse this one with frames with more than  2 columns  and with other operations than just additions. So this one is more generic approach. I'm sorry I've missed that out in the original question

Answer (score 4):

Just `add`

```
source1.set_index('key').add(source2.set_index('key'), fill_value=0)
```

If `key` is already the index, just use

```
source1.add(source2, fill_value=0)
```

You man want to `.reset_index()` at the end if you don't want `key` as index

Comment: That was my exact solution.

Comment: That's better than my first attempt, +1

Comment: Thanks for the input guys ! ;}

Comment: Note that this assumes that the key columns have no duplicates (which may be a reasonable assumption here).